# How to get the Http or Https request url from Selenium with java When Button Click Done

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium

I am working on one Automation project using selenium and java and our application is single page application type, So
 I have one requirement like I need to extract the Http or Https Request URL from the browser when I click on Submit button.I need to use that URL in my further automation.
I can able to see that URL in Developer tools network tab, But Am unable to get it.
Could you please anyone help me in this.

Comment: Post More Details, A screenshot of what you want to get will be helpful

Comment: Hi Kushal, I want to extract the URL from network section in the developer tool though Java or Selenium.

Comment: When I pass startdate and end date and click on update report button, one request URL is triggered.I need to Extract the URL and change the response format and used for further. Below is the sample URL

Comment: **Request URL:**http://xyz.eng.abc.com/bactalkreports?Duration=daily&EndDate=03%2F25%2F2018+11:59:59+PM&ReportID=12&SID=3&SID=1&SID=2&SID=4&SID=5&StartDate=03%2F25%2F2018+12:00:00+AM&ars:command=reportExec&ars:query=%2FADVSC2_TEST2_ARSReportTemplates%2FStandardTemplates%2FAlarm+Dashboard+Occurrence&ars:reportname=LM_RC5_Alarm+Dashboard+Occurrence&rc:Format=HTML5&rc:HTMLFragment=False&rc:Section=1&rc:Toolbar=False&rc:zoom=70%25&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Command=Render

Comment: Not possible via Selenium